# Is there a way to schedule a post on gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I'm using gatsby-transformer-remark on gatsbyjs to create posts and I want to schedule some post. Can this be done?

Comment: Here is a solution using a GitHub action: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/schedule-posts-gatsby-netlify/

Answer (score 1):

I see two main ways of doing this. Either rebuild the site on a schedule or hide the posts in your UI code (I wouldn't recommend that, but might be easier to do):

1. Have a cron job every X minutes that will build & deploy your Gatsby site. In your build logic (most likely your code at `gatsby-node.js`) only build pages / posts that you want to go live at the given time of the build. Using filtering on your GraphQL query, you could only build posts that have a publication date equal or superior to the current time.
2. In your posts, using a "publicationDate" field (name is up to you), set that field for when you want the blog post to go live and in your app hide any posts that aren't supposed to be live. This will kinda work, but posts will still exist and if you have a sitemap for example, they'll show there.